# How to make where clause with comparing two fields in SqlKorma (clojure)

Tags: postgresql, clojure, korma

I'm using Postgresql and sqlkorma 0.4.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id serial PRIMARY KEY, 
   a integer NOT NULL, b integer NOT NULL);
```

How to make:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE a > b
```

I've tried

```
(defentity mytable
       (pk :id)
       (table :mytable))
```

and

```
(select table mytable
  (fields :a :b)
  (where (> a b)))
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(sql-only
  (select my-table (where {:a [> :b]})))
;; => "SELECT `my-table`.* FROM `my-table` WHERE (`my-table`.`a` > `my-table`.`b`)"
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is a valid answer but I suggest looking at Yesql:

https://github.com/krisajenkins/yesql

In most case, you don't need a DSL just to repeat what SQL has already done.

I used to work with Korma a lot myself and found myself spending way too much time just converting SQL to Korma syntax like this.

Comment: But what do you mean? Should I write queries in sql? I think DSL has such advantage as syntax checking by IDE.

Comment: Korma's last release was August 27th 2014 and the last commit was 17 days ago (Dec 26th 2014). I think it's safe to say it is still maintained.

Comment: @Curiosity Please spend some time reading Yesql's Readme. Clojure DSL for SQL can't be as good as plain text SQL in IDEs' support.

Comment: @Kyle Okay, I was wrong about Korma's maintenance. Thanks for pointing out it